# Convert a 4 byte data to int in C

Tags: c

I need to convert 4 byte data which is in below format to a original int value . I cannot change the below assignment of int to 4 bytes.

```
int main() {
    //code

    int num = 1000;

    char a[4];
    a[0] = ( char )(num>>24)  ;
    a[1] = ( char )(num>>16) ;
    a[2] = ( char )(num>>8) ;
    a[3] = ( char )num ;


    printf("Original number is:%d\n", (a[0] << 24 | a[1] << 16 | a[2] << 8 | a[3] ) );
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting output to be 1000, but output is 768. How do we restore the original number from above byte array ?Is this an endianess issue ?

Comment: this should be re-opened, the problem isn't a typo. `a[x]` is a char, most likely 8 bits. Shifting that by 24, 16, or 8 shifts beyond the bit size,  you'll need to cast each `a[x]` to a larger data type before shifting, something like `unsigned int`

Comment: Please note that char is signed and num is signed. When you perform the >> (right shift), the sign will be preserved. Your code will behave better for positive num than negative.

Comment: @yano: It’s promoted for the shift; the issue is just the signedness.

Comment: @yano: `char` values are promoted in `int` in shift operations. The shifts by 16 and 8 are fine, provided one is using a C implementation in which `int` is 32 bits. The shift by 24 would be a problem if the value to be restored were negative, as then there are overflow issues.

Comment: @Ry and Eric, wow, didn't know that. Thanks. I need to downvote my own comment.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: `char` has implementation-defined signedness, it's not specified to be `signed` or `unsigned` by the standard. And for `signed` values, right-shift is itself implementation-defined as well (it might preserve the sign, it might not).

Comment: It works with `unsigned char` instead of `char`

Comment: Bitwise operations with signed types can get a little weird. I suggest you work with `unsigned char` and `unsigned int` on all variables involved in the bitwise operations.

Comment: Honestly I don't even know why signed bitwise operations exist. Maybe I should look into that.

Comment: @at77: `(unsigned char)a[0] << 24` will have undefined behavior if the high bit of `a[0]` is set. (It is not with the value 1000 given in the example code in the question, but it cannot be used in the general case with values that originate from signed `int` values.) In shifts, `unsigned char` operands will be promoted to `int`, but `unsigned int` is needed to get a well defined shift result. Unfortunately, then there is no good “clean” way to convert the `unsigned int` to `int`.

Answer (score 4):

> `a[0] = ( char )(num>>24)  ;`

That works “okay” in this example. However, in situations where `num` is negative, the result is implementation-defined (C 2018 6.5.7 5).

In the remaining assignments to `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`, values that may exceed the range of `char` will be converted to `char` automatically. If `char` is signed, the results of these conversions are implementation-defined or a signal is raised (6.3.1.3 3). So that is a problem we will have to fix, below.

First, for `num` = 1000, let’s suppose that −24 is stored in `a[3]`. This is the result we would get by taking the low eight bits of 1000 and putting them in an eight-bit two’s complement `char`, which is likely what your implementation uses. Then, we have `a[0]` = 0, `a[1]` = 0, `a[2]` = 3, and `a[3]` = −24.

Now let’s consider `a[0] << 24 | a[1] << 16 | a[2] << 8 | a[3]`.

`a[0] << 24` and `a[1] << 16` both yield 0. `a[2] << 8` is `3 << 8`, which produces 768, or 300 in hexadecimal. `a[3]` is −24. While `a[3]` is a `char`, it is promoted to an `int` when used in an expression (6.3.1.1 2). Still assuming your C implementation uses two’s complement, the binary for −24 is 11111111111111111111111111101000, or ffffffe8 in hexadecimal.

When we bitwise OR 300 and ffffffe8, the result is ffffffe8, which, in a 32-bit two’s complement `int`, is −24.

The easiest way to fix this is to change `char a[4];` to `unsigned char a[4];`. That avoids any negative `char` values.

However, to make your code completely work for any value of `int` (assuming it is four bytes and two’s complement), we need to make some other changes:

```
unsigned char a[4];

/*  Convert the signed num to unsigned before shifting.
    Shifts of unsigned values are better defined than shifts
    of signed values.
*/
a[0] = (unsigned) num >> 24;
a[1] = (unsigned) num >> 16;
a[2] = (unsigned) num >>  8;
a[3] = (unsigned) num;
/*  The cast in the last assignment is not really needed since
    we are assigning to an unsigned char, and it will be converted
    as desired, but we keep it for uniformity.
*/

//  Reconstruct the value using all unsigned values.
unsigned u = (unsigned) a[0] << 24 | (unsigned) a[1] << 16 | (unsigned) a[2] << 8 | a[3];

/*  Copy the bits into an int.  (Include <string.h> to get memcpy.)
    Note:  It is easy to go from signed to unsigned because the C standard
    completely defines that conversion.  For unsigned to signed, the
    conversion is not completely defined, so we have to use some indirect
    method to get the bits into an int.
*/
int i;
memcpy(&i, &u, sizeof i);

printf("Original number:  %d.\n", i);
```

We need to use an `unsigned` value to reconstruct the bits because C’s shift operators are not well defined for signed values, especially when we want to shift a bit into the sign bit. Once we have the bits in the `unsigned` object, we can copy them into an `int`.

Comment: @chux: I added a note just before the `memcpy` about how C completely defines signed to unsigned but not vice-versa.

Comment: This causes UB on a 16-bit int system; so I suggest using `uint32_t` as the type